# How to prevent automatic conversion of dashes to &ndash;

Tags: formatting

When I put -- into a post it is automatically converted to the – `&ndash;` character in the output by wordpress.

How can I get normal `'--'` double dashes in my content.

Answer (score 8):

In your `functions.php`:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

And the same for `the_excerpt` or `the_title` (if required).

Comment: what else does this disable, or does it just target the -- conversion?

Comment: @radman [View codex - wptexturize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize#Notes) for what this function does, obviously filtering this function will stop all other conversions mentioned there.

Comment: Is there a way to disable 'wptexture' specifically for embeds (github gists)? I've had readers on my blog unable to copy a line from a gist with a minus sign. They would get syntax errors because it was replaced by an emdash.

Comment: @Antonvh What is the embed plugin/code you're using? I'm not aware of core WordPress supporting gist embeds.

Comment: I used the default Gutenberg embed URL block. Pasted a link to my gist inside: https://gist.github.com/antonvh/695ab1c36b61171714a84f700858cdb3

Comment: If I embed the gist using raw HTML, within <script> tags, it looks exactly the same for the user, but the dashes don't get replaced!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: If you are using WordPress, in the beginning of your file `single.php` add these lines:

```
<?php
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wptexturize' );
?>
```

And do your test. I am 99.99% sure that will work because I had the same problem and I fixed it using that lines 10 seconds ago. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that override the origin function of `wptexturize` and update all related filters.

```
define('EXCERPT_RARELY_2', '{[2}]');
function wptexturize_custom($text = '')
{
    $text = preg_replace('!(^|[^\-])\-\-([^\-]|$)!', '$1' . EXCERPT_RARELY_2 . '$2', $text);

    // get through origin filter
    $text = wptexturize($text);

    return str_replace(EXCERPT_RARELY_2, '--', $text);
}

// remove default filter
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

// add custom filter
add_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize_custom');

// remove default filter
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');

// add custom filter
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize_custom');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the OP and the solution proposed by @TheDeadMedic *almost* worked for me.
But my WP version has several function_*something*.php files and I had to add this to them all (making sure to add them **after** the php opening code <?php):

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wptexturize' );
```

Of course only one of them would be needed if you only want to remove the filter for titles, content or excerpt.