# Formatting with <pre>

Tags: formatting, pre

I'm building a site that doesn't want any styling applied to the entry-content, because it should keep the formatting of the text.

Bizarly, it works on old entries, but new entries via the front-end system fail:
`http://madebylars.nl/music/?page_id=373`

#### Example:

This one works:

```
http://madebylars.nl/music/?tab=the-tallest-man-on-earth-love-is-all
```

This one doesn't:

```
http://madebylars.nl/music/?tab=the-tallest-man-on-earth-like-the-wheel
```

They both look fine in the WordPress back-end, but only one of them looks nice on the front-end. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I'm already wrapping the whole text in `<pre>` tags and stripping wp-content of html-tags.

This is the styling I use (on both!):

```
pre {
    background: none; 
    font: 13px "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 1.625em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0.75em 1.625em;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    margin: 1em 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pages you are linking use two different characters, one is the `&mdash` and the other I don't know the name, it does not translates into an Html entity...

Original:

`2——-2——-7——-7——-|` <-- Mixed characters

Using the character that works:

`2---2---7---7---|` <-- This one is not `&mdash`.

You may consider using a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to encapsulate the tabs, so you can manipulate the characters and substitute faulty ones.

Comment: After some research it came out that WordPress, or more precisely "wp-texturize", automatically converts double dashes '--' to &ndash;.

Apparently, there is an &ndash; and an &mdash;. The first corresponds to the width of the letter "n", the second to the width of the letter "m". Interesting.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash

I have now solved this as follows 
`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );` in functions.php. Thanks guys!

Comment: @LarsvanPeij, glad to know, maybe you could write an Answer explaining how you solved this.

Answer (score 2):

After some research it came out that WordPress, or more precisely "wp-texturize", automatically converts double dashes '--' to `&ndash;`.

Apparently, there is an `&ndash;` and an `&mdash;`. The first corresponds to the width of the letter "n", the second to the width of the letter "m". Interesting.

wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/… I have now solved this as follows:

`<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' ); ?>`

Put this in functions.php. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why it does not work: invalid markup, stripping content also removes `<div>`s (which in some cases are creating line breaks in wordpress editor) and so on.

Actually I think you should get the contents of the post directly from the database or use  `$post->post_content` and `strip_tags` on it.

But check all of the formatting first on a static page. Create a dummy testing.php whithout any styles and output in it your code for a single post. Test it for various posts and if it works there it will work on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm way off-base and totally misunderstanding the question, in the second link (the one that doesn't work), different lines have a different number of characters. Here's the strings directly under **INTRO**

```
First string:  —————-| (7 chars)
Second string: ———-0—–| (8 chars)
Third string:  ——0——-0-| (9 chars)
```

Are you saying you want it to look like this:

```
First string:  ———————-| (9 chars)
Second string: ————-0—–| (9 chars)
Third string:  ——0——-0-| (9 chars)
```

Comment: Actually, in the backend both sites are correct. So the faulty one has 9 chars per line in the backend.

Comment: but yes, I want it to look like your second example. Somehow on the frontend it gets back from 9 to 7/8/9 chars.